# Fitting a distribution to my data, and estimating future transactions

Tags: curve-fitting

Assuming that I have a list of transactions generated by an unknown process.

After fitting a distribution to my data I wish to report the projected sum of n transactions - assuming that it's generated by the same process.

is it correct to report n * lower bound (2.5 percentile), n * 50th percentile and n *97.5th percentile as the probable range of total transactions that we will observe?

Comment: Probably not - but it depends on how different transactions are related to each other.  Is it plausible that all $n$ could be at the bottom end, or all $n$ could be at the top end?

Comment: You say the process is unknown. Some assumptions may be necessary to make progress (such as the particular form of dependence between the n values, or that they're independent). If you assume independence, you needn't necessarily fit a distribution; if the sample size is reasonably large, you could, for example, use a bootstrap. (If this is for a class, it's also plausible you're expected to use an large sample approximation for the distribution of the sum.) ... using the same data to choose a model and fit / forecast the model impacts the properties of the predictions. ... ctd

Comment: ctd... If you're set on that 'find and fit a distribution' path, there are ways to avoid using the same values twice.